# requestAnimationFrame not working with decimal numbers below 1

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

**requestAnimationFrame** doesnt work with decimals for some reason. Usually when animating in canvas I can work with decimals but in the case of dom elements I fail. As you can see below, I am animating the left position of a single div which works for n > 1 but not n < 1 (0.1, 0.2 etc).

Why is this the case?

https://jsfiddle.net/m1qzqvu8

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]

function fn(){
var x = parseInt(elem.style.left);
x += 0.4
elem.style.left = x + "px"
    requestAnimationFrame(fn)
}

fn()
```

The reason im trying to make this work is speed. I need to make things slower or faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `parseInt`. This rounds decimal values to integers, so you are always getting `parseInt(10.4) + 0.4 = 10 + 0.4 = 10.4`, iterating endlessly.

Using parseFloat should correct the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/m1qzqvu8/1/

Note: you should always provide a radix argument to `parseInt`.

Comment: Just found out: parseFloat